# Publishing Visual Studio website to GoDaddy

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, publish, webdeploy

I have published my website onto GoDaddy before but for some reason this time I ran into a problem. I am unable to validate the connection and an image is provided below. I tried by microsoft account and GoDaddy account, and I still can't validate the connection. Am I forgetting something? Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your credentials are invalid. I suggest you to check if your username and password are the correct ones (I guess it is). On the other hand, it could be better to file a ticket to Godaddy in order to check if your account or password can be expired/blocked.

Comment: I will definitely file a ticket to GoDaddy. Just to clarify, the username and password they are asking is it the GoDaddy account or the Microsoft Visual Studio account?

Comment: You are trying to connect to Godaddy server, so it should be your Godaddy user.